# Importing Data From One database to another

Tags: sql

I wanted to know that, Suppose I have a table in one database with say 1000 records and I have similar table in another database with say 500 records.

Now my question is If I will try to import data from say DB1.Tbl1 to DB2.Tbl1, then what will happen? Is there any possibilities of duplicacy of the data?

I wanted the records of DB1.Tbl1 to copy into DB2.Tbl1 table. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: Might help if you specify DBMS.

Comment: It depends on exact schema of both tables and how you actually do your import. If your table schema allows duplicates then you have a choice of leaving them, removing them, or merging them. To get a meaningful answer you have to be way more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same data in both tables you can first truncate 2nd table after that you can import data from 1st table by Insert Command or "import data" task

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Tbl1 SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.Tbl2
```

This just moves the data. If you want to move the table definition, you have to do something else.

Note that, SQL Server Management Studio's "Import Data" task (right-click on the DB name, then tasks) will do most of this for you. Run it from the database you want to copy the data into.

If the tables don't exist it will create them for you, but you'll probably have to recreate any indexes. If the tables do exist, it will append the new data by default but you can adjust that (edit mappings) so it will delete all existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

We can copy all columns from one table to another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or we can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```